# How to getting started with spring batch using ant?

Tags: spring, ant, batch-processing

I'm learning java spring batch and I'm trying to get librairies, on tutorials I only see getting librairies with maven2 but I only have ant (I can't get maven or gradle) so how can I do for the dependencies? I have to create an pom.xml and then?

Comment: If you can get ant, and download stuff you surely can get maven... With ant you have to search the internet for jar files, download them and figure out which jars (and versions) you need to mix.

Comment: Ant doesn't have built in dependency management, but you can use Ivy for this, or (my personal preference) the Maven Ant tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) is a plugin that gives your ANT build Maven superpowers :-)

The following is an example of the [retrieve task](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/retrieve.html) that will populate a "lib" directory.

```
<ivy:retrieve pattern="${lib.dir}/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]">
    <dependency org="org.springframework.batch" name="spring-batch-core" rev="3.0.7.RELEASE" conf="default"/>
</ivy:retrieve>
```

Alternatively you can specify your project's dependencies in a separate [ivy.xml](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile.html) file.

## Example

Full working example.

```
├── build.xml
└── lib
    ├── aopalliance-1.0.jar
    ├── com.ibm.jbatch-tck-spi-1.0.jar
    ├── commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
    ├── javax.batch-api-1.0.jar
    ├── jettison-1.2.jar
    ├── spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
    ├── spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
    ├── spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar
    ├── spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
    ├── spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
    ├── spring-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
    ├── spring-expression-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
    ├── spring-retry-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar
    ├── spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
    ├── xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar
    ├── xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
    └── xstream-1.4.7.jar
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="compile" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">

    <!--
    ================
    Build properties
    ================
    -->
    <property name="src.dir"          location="src/main/java"/>
    <property name="resources.dir"    location="src/main/resources"/>
    <property name="test.src.dir"     location="src/test/java"/>
    <property name="build.dir"        location="build"/>
    <property name="lib.dir"          location="lib"/>
    <property name="dist.dir"         location="${build.dir}/dist"/>

    <property name="jar.main.class" value="org.demo.App"/>
    <property name="jar.file"       value="${dist.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>

    <available classname="org.apache.ivy.Main" property="ivy.installed"/> 

    <!--
    ===============
    Compile targets
    ===============
    -->
    <target name="resolve" depends="install-ivy">
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="${lib.dir}/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]">
            <dependency org="org.springframework.batch" name="spring-batch-core" rev="3.0.7.RELEASE" conf="default"/>
        </ivy:retrieve>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="resolve">
    </target>

    <!--
    ===========
    Install ivy
    ===========
    -->
    <target name="install-ivy" unless="ivy.installed">
        <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
        <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/ivy.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.4.0/ivy-2.4.0.jar"/>
        <fail message="Ivy has been installed. Run the build again"/>
    </target>

    <!--
    =============
    Clean targets
    =============
    -->
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <delete dir="${lib.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-all" depends="clean">
        <ivy:cleancache/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Notes:

- There is a target that will install ivy if it's missng
- There is also a target that will optionally purge ivy's download cache.